# Web service to create a Core Data database

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, cocoa, core-data

I have an iOS app for which i have to develop a web service that will create and populate a Core Data database (depending on user rights) in order to get it back to the app.

What do you recommend?

Should I create a Core Data Command Line Tool in order to use it from any Web Service?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain better your goal? It's not very clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: What are you going to be running your web service on? Why are you returning a whole database instead of a more generic form of information such as a JSON structure that the receiving app can create the database from?

Comment: The goal is to improve performance by generating the database on the server. The server will be more efficient to generate the database. Also caching the result for the different users profiles will be even faster.

There are no limits on what the Web Service will running on...